# Target specific package when running Grails integration tests using Gradle

Tags: grails, gradle, gradlew, grails-3.1

I can target a specific package with the grails command:

```
grails test-app com.mypackage.* -integration
```

How to do the same using Gradle wrapper?
Tried `./gradlew integrationTest com.mypackage.*`, but no luck.

(Grails 3.1.10, Gradle wrapper 2.13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./gradlew iT --tests "com.mypackage.*"
```